# Module extend and class_eval in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

i'm testing metaprogramming and i have one case i don't understand:

```
module Bar
 def self.append_features klass
   klass.class_eval do
     def self.a
       puts 'a'
     end
   end
 end
end

class Foo
 extend Bar
end
```

Where is define "a" method?
Because:

Foo.new.a, Foo.a and Class.a don't works!

if i use include instead of extend in Foo class, method "a" is define for Class Foo (Foo.a works), i thought : if the "self" for include = Class, "self" for extend = Metaclass, but no.

Can explain where is method "a"?

Answer (score 6):

[`append_features`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-append_features) is a hook method in ruby,which is being called, when you did `include Bar`. Now it is adding the class method `a` to the class `Bar`, then it makes available the class method `a` to `Foo`.

Let me explain you how that method `a` became the class method of `Bar`. When you did `include Bar`, hook method gets called, and its parameter `klass` is set to `Bar`. Now `klass.class_eval {..}`, `class_eval` set `self` inside the block `{..}` as `Bar`. Now `def self.a;puts 'a';end` means actually `def Bar.a;puts 'a';end`.

```
module Bar
 def self.append_features klass
   klass.class_eval do
     def self.a
       puts 'a'
     end
   end
 end
end

class Foo
 include Bar
end

Foo.a # => a
```

> Where is define "a" method? Because: Foo.new.a, Foo.a and Class.a don't works!

This is because you did `extend Bar`,which did not call the hook method `append_features`. So class method `a` has not been defined inside the class `Bar`,as you expected.

Comment: +1 Interesting! :) Didn't know about `append_features`; never wondered about `extend` and `include` differences before.

Comment: @kiddorails It's a wise idea to have Ruby's API reference at hand so with a simple `ri append_features` or even `ri Module.append_features` can give you enough information before posting here on SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

"When this module is *included* in another, Ruby calls append_features in this module" ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-append_features)) - you `extended` Bar, not `included` Bar. Inclusion and extension do somewhat different things, beyond changing the definition of `self` - for instance, their hook methods are different. I suspect that `append_features` is never being called at all in your case where you `extend` Bar.